# Is there a cross-browser solution to create a directory on a client?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

As ActiveXObjects are compatible with IE only, can any one give me an alternate filesystem object which does the same function as activeX and is compatible with chrome browser?

Comment: You can't do it in Chrome (or any other non-IE browser) without having the user install a browser extension or plugin.

Comment: @Juhana which plugin must be installed with the browser?? i hv tried with IE based tab but its not working :(

Comment: The plugin you'd make that would have the feature you want. What I'm trying to say is that due to security issues what you want to do is very hard, and would always require the user to manually install extra stuff on their computer or the very least agree for the browser to give the web site access to the filesystem, if it's possible with a Java applet or Flash (I don't know if it is.)

Comment: @Juhana yup it is possible to create folders with jsp(java server page) but when i deploy my plug in to the browser then it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the HTML5 File API http://html5demos.com/file-api

You can save up to 25 megabytes without requesting the user permission, may vary from browser to browser. You can't access the disk, only a special folder create for your domain.

However I'm not sure about what you want.

Comment: i m creating an extension for chrome browser which downloads a file and i don't want that to be saved in downloads folder instead i need to create my own folder and store my downloaded file there so i m stuck in creating folders there is no API in java script which helps to create folder...